# Show a table of results per update (updates defined by user)

Tags: java, android, dynamic

I want to show a table of results like this one:

[image]

once every time time the program is updated. The tables should be in a **row** next to each other with the option to scroll and view all of them, two at a time(there will be two on screen at any one time). 

I have an update() method that does all the work of the number crunching and provides output. So I am guessing a loop like this:

```
public void showResults(){
        MainActivity.e1.start();
        while (MainActivity.e1.getCurrentTime() < MainActivity.e1.getEndTime()){
            MainActivity.e1.update();
            // Print a table.
        }
    }
```

So a horizontalScrollView would be good, with a linearLayout (horizontal). My question is this:
 **How can I create and show a table every time an update occurs?**

For example, if the user specifies 500 updates, is there a way to just say "create and show a table for each one of these updates" without manually creating tableViews in the layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I did this is to have a single **TableRow** inside a **TableView** inside a **scrollView**. That way I can add as many tables as is necessary for the number of updates.  
 A linearLayout would also have worked but TableView allows me to add tables underneath in the same view as TableRows without clogging it all up with too many LinearViews.